# Larry Csonka and the Chocolate Factory: confirmation of existence

Tags: theater

(**Note:** Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300800/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-a-broadway-show brought me here.)

My friend and I were chatting about Miami fullback Larry Csonka the other day (it was a *Mystery Science Theater 3000* discussion) and perusing [his Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Csonka) page I came along this intriguing paragraph:

> During the 1971 off season Csonka starred in the critically well received off Broadway play of "Larry Csonka and the Chocolate Factory". Due to financial backing and Larry's contract with the Dolphins barring him from any off season "strenuous activity" the play never gained commercial success, but for his efforts Csonka was nominated in the 1972 Obie Award for best Actor, where he eventually lost to Douglas Rain for his role in Vivat! Vivat Regina!

References to back this section up included Larry's IMDB page (there's no reference to the show on there) and the Obie Awards archives (if you search for 1972 you only get a list of winners).

My question: Besides this mention on Wikipedia, is there any evidence out there to confirm this was actually a show?

Comment: No evidence this existed that I can find online.

Comment: You are making the mistake of assuming that Wikipaedia is a reliable source of information.

Comment: @Chenmunka I take your point, but more to my question I was asking if this specific bit of information on the Wikipedia page was reliable. It looks like it's not so far.

Comment: *Willie Wonka and the Chocolate Factory* [(see IMDB)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067992/) was a 1971 musical film based on Roald Dahl's book *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory*. Surely the fact that Csonka rhymes with *Wonka* is not irrelevant.

Comment: The claim was added to the article by an anonymous user in [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Larry_Csonka&diff=prev&oldid=889106585) in March 2019, and the spurious citations in [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Larry_Csonka&diff=prev&oldid=889107400) by the same user. Clearly the claim is a joke.

Comment: @GarethRees I am both happy and sad at that news. Thank you for doing the research. If you turn this comment into an answer I'll mark it as the answer.